# Files not found in the current working dir

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, working-directory

I have a really basic question. I'm trying to run STAR to align some reads to a sequencing experiment. I have around 30 samples. I firstly splitted the fast.gz files in 30 folders according to the sample of origin. In other words in each folder corresponding to a Sample* there are 4 files named *.fastq.gz (4 because of 4 lanes). I'm trying to loop STAR in each folder in this way:

```
for i in Sample*/;
do
cd $i;
qsub my_align_script.sh;
cd ..; done
```

where my_align_script.sh contains the following:

```
for i in *fastq.gz; do
STAR  --runMode alignReads --genomeLoad  LoadAndKeep --readFilesCommand zcat --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted --genomeDir "path" --readFilesIn $i ${i%.fastq.gz}.fastq.gz --runThreadN 10 --outFileNamePrefix ${i%.fastq.gz}
done
```

but unfortunately it seems not to find any *fast.gz file.

I tried to force to look in the current working dir of each Sample* folder specifying cd $path at the beginning but nothing when I run the for loop to launch jobs over folders.

Comment: If you are submitting to a cluster (guessing from `qsub`), then cluster has no idea where the file is?

Comment: Are they single end or pair end? What are you trying to achieve with `--readFilesIn $i ${i%.fastq.gz}.fastq.gz`? It looks like you are passing `$i` two times, with the second substituting `.fastq.gz` by the same string. Also, don't forget to remove the loaded genome from memory at the end. Having the actual error could help. Make sure that the input files are in a shared dir, accessible from the compute nodes.

Comment: @Gautam It is "fastq.gz", "fast.gz" is just a typo in the text, not in the code. Code wants to find "fastq.gz" as intended. It is a gzipped [fastq format file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format)

Comment: Sorry if I have left out some information. The alignment is not paired-end.

Comment: You should probably give the exact error message you have. Sanity check: Do you have a copy of (or a link to) `my_align_script.sh` in every `Sample*` directory?

Comment: Guys error solved now. The problem was in STAR that pointed to the home dir where the .fastq.gz were not as obvious

Comment: @Bfu38 Please post your solution/comment as an answer.